# Making a radios form element required

Tags: forms

How can I make *which_option* required so that users are forced to select an option?

```
$options = array(
  'Design1' => t('Design 1'),
  'Design2' => t('Design 2'),           
);

$form['which_option'] = array(
  '#name' => 'which_option',        
  '#id' => 'which_option',
  '#type' => 'radios',           
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#options' => $options,
  '#default_value' => isset($which_option) ? $which_option : NULL,
  '#prefix' => '<br><hr><br><p>If you&apos;re a lucky winner, tell us which bag you would like</p><br><div class="label-wrap">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

Comment: Just as you did: `'#required' => TRUE`, flush cache, done.

Comment: Which is what I thought but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code used from Drupal core, I found that [book.admin.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21book%21book.admin.inc/7.x) uses the following code, to define a require radios element.

```
$types = node_type_get_names();

$form['book_child_type'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => t('Content type for child pages'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('book_child_type', 'book'),
  '#options' => $types,
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

The code you shown doesn't work because *#default_value* is set to `NULL`.

```
'#default_value' => isset($which_option) ? $which_option : NULL,
```

You don't show how `$which_option` is initialized; either that variable is never initialized, or it is not initialized when you tested the code. In both the cases, `isset($which_option)` returns `FALSE` and *#default_value* is set to `NULL`.

Instead of that, the code should avoid setting *#default_value*, which is what form_test.module (a module for testing form elements) does. (See the first form element in the following code; the other form elements are shown to make a comparison.)

```
$form['radios'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => 'Radios',
  '#options' => $options,
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['radios_optional'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => 'Radios (optional)',
  '#options' => $options,
);
$form['radios_optional_default_value_false'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => 'Radios (optional, with a default value of FALSE)',
  '#options' => $options,
  '#default_value' => FALSE,
);
```

Notice the first radios element, which is required, doesn't have any *#default_value* property set.

Comment: As usual, don't edit the code of an enabled module. First disable it, edit the code, and re-enable the module.

Comment: ok I will take the default line out and try it.

Comment: $options = array(
   'Design1' => t('Design 1'),
   'Design2' => t('Design 2'),    
  );
        $form['which_option'] = array (
            '#name' => 'which_option',  
            '#id' => 'which_option',
            '#type' => 'radios',           
            '#required' => TRUE,
   '#options' => $options,   
            '#prefix' => '<br><hr><br
   <p>If you&apos;re a lucky winner, tell us which bag you would like</p><br><div class="label-wrap">',
             '#suffix' => '</div>',
        );

Comment: It still doesn't work. the '#required' => TRUE, is ignored

Comment: I didn't think it would as that is what I tried originally

Comment: if (trim($which_option) !== "Design1" && trim($which_option) !== "Design2") {
   
   $form_state->setErrorByName('which_option', $this->t('Please select which option you prefer.'));
  }

Comment: Doesn't work either. I f I use one of the other names instead of if (trim($which_option) !== "Design1" && trim($which_option) !== "Design2") {

Comment: Doesn't work either. It is fine if I use something other than which-option